# Parallel Linq: Ordered treatment

Tags: c#, linq, parallel-processing

I'm following the material from the 70-516 MS exam, and I came across the section where they explain that we can ensure an ordered treatment while doing parallel processing if we use the AsOrdered method.

However, running the example below does not ouput the results in order.

Basically, the sample code below starts with an enumerable collection of 10 integers, which is then parallelised, then ordered and finally filtered by only selecting element for which the Compute function returns a even number. The Compute function just returns the input, after a 1 sec delay

```
private void TestLinqParallel()
    {
        Stopwatch sw = new Stopwatch();
        sw.Start();
        var source = Enumerable.Range(1, 10).AsParallel().AsOrdered();
        var evenNums = from num in source
                       where Compute(num) % 2 == 0
                       select num;
        evenNums.ForAll(ev =>
        {
            Debug.WriteLine(string.Format("{0} on Thread {1}", ev, Thread.CurrentThread.GetHashCode()));

        });
        sw.Stop();
        Debug.WriteLine(string.Format("Done {0}", sw.Elapsed));
    }
    public int Compute(int num)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine(string.Format("Computing {0} on Thread {1}", num, Thread.CurrentThread.GetHashCode()));
        Thread.Sleep(1000);
        return num;
    }
```

The book states

> The results are ordered, at least for the even numbers, which is what
>   the AsOrdered extension method is guaranteeing.

But here are my results.. The processing of 4 comes before the processing of 2

```
Computing 4 on Thread 11
Computing 3 on Thread 10
Computing 2 on Thread 12
Computing 1 on Thread 6
4 on Thread 11
Computing 7 on Thread 11
Computing 6 on Thread 6
2 on Thread 12
Computing 8 on Thread 12
Computing 5 on Thread 10
Computing 9 on Thread 11
6 on Thread 6
Computing 10 on Thread 6
8 on Thread 12
10 on Thread 6
Done 00:00:03.0561023
```

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 3):

`ForAll` is parallelized. That means that all ordering guarantees go out of the Window because your code body is executed concurrently. Try a `foreach` loop.